# time to write read file?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Here's a strange one...is there anyway of using powershell to see how long it takes to write a file?

So, if I create a file - can powershell tell me how long it took to create that file (ie 25ms or whatever the number is). Also, if I delete a file can it also tell me the time?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Measure-Command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176899.aspx) can do this for you.

e.g.

Measure-Command { new-item -Path test.txt -ItemType File -Force }

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
$before = Get-Date
# do stuff
$after = Get-Date
echo ($after - $before).TotalMilliseconds
```